# Limit the database size with SQL Server Express LocalDB

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-express, localdb

I'm creating a database for system that has a small (16Gb) hard disc. I would like to limit the size of the database to 512Mb so that I still have room on the disc for other applications.

I'm having trouble finding a way to limit the maximum size of a database when using SQL Server Express `LocalDB` with Entity Framework 5 code first. I have found examples on how to limit the database for SQL Server CE using the `Max Database Size` parameter, but that throws a `Keyword not supported` exception with `LocalDB`.

Is there any way to limit the maximum size of the `.mdf` file when using `LocalDB`?

Here is the connection string that I'm using.

```
<add name="LiteDatabase"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\V11.0; Initial Catalog=LiteDB; AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\Data\LiteDB.mdf; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option that can be specified declaratively (in the e.g. connection string or something like that).

But since it's SQL Server **Express**, it's limited to 10 GB in size anyway (system limitation)

Answer (score 0):

Since LocalDB uses the same format as normal Sql Server, you might be able to create the DB initially using normal Sql Server and set the limit there.  If you go to create the database, you could copy it to the location and then attach to it using local DB.  Of course this assumes that you're creating the DB as part of some installation procedure.

Comment: I'm currently letting EF code first create the database. Is there a way to override the code first database creation?